# centralizar as 4 td com esses 3 icones alinhados, quero deixar igual a imagem que irei inserir abaixo. tudo esta dentro da: <table> <td> e <tr>

Tags: html, css, imagem, table, text

1. HTML:

[quero deixar os 3 icones alinados porem com as +-4 td][1]

Ser Tech é sair na frente.

Ensino técnico + médio

Ser Tech é já estar preparado.

para o mercado de trabalho.

Ser Tech é ter a liberdade de

escolher qual caminho

profissional seguir.

2. CSS:
   .areaverde{
   background-color: #89f668;
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
   color: rgb(102, 16, 131);
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   vertical-align: middle;}
   #icones_texto{
   margin-top: -10px;
   size: 18px;
   line-height: 16px;
   font-weight: 700;
   }
   #icone_01{

}
#icone_02{

}
#icone_03{
}
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpZMU.png

Comment: Importante você pesquisar se não existe post similar no site, e caso não,[edit] sua pergunta fornecendo um [mcve] do problema e explicar como tentou resolver, e descrever o mais objetivamente possível qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Ao editar, automaticamente sua pergunta é destacada para uma revisão e a comunidade reavalia os votos e o fechamento. Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.