# alinhar essas 3 imagens e textos do código para que tenha o resultado dessa imagem

Tags: html, css, imagem, table, css-centering

```
<body><class="areaverde">
<td id="icone_01"><img src="imagens do site/icone01.png" alt=""><div id="icones_texto"><p>Ser Tech é sair na frente.</p></div><div id="icones_texto"><p>Ensino técnico + médio</p></div></td>
<td colspan="2" id="icone_02"><img src="imagens do site/icone02.png" alt=""><div id="icones_texto"><p>Ser Tech é já estar preparado.</p></div><div id="icones_texto"><p>para o mercado de trabalho.</p></div></td>
<td></td>
<td id="icone_03"><img src="imagens do site/icone04.png" alt=""><div id="icones_texto"><p>Ser Tech é ter a liberdade de</p></div><div id="icones_texto"><p>escolher qual caminho</p></div><div id="icones_texto"><p>profissional seguir.</p></div></td>
```

CSS:
.areaverde{
background-color: #89f668;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: rgb(102, 16, 131);
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;}
#icones_texto{
margin-top: -10px;
size: 18px;
line-height: 16px;
font-weight: 700;
}
#icone_01{

}
#icone_02{

}
#icone_03{

}[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPuCw.png)

Comment: Não duplique postagens, queira acessar [seu post original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/593517/70) e fazer como orientado lá.